# AngularJS show textarea on link click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of links:

```
$scope.links = [{
   URL: ''    
}];
```

Then I show those links in the view using `data-ng-repeat`.

How can I do so that when the user click's any of the links under it will show a textbox? If clicked again the textbox will disappear?

So if the html is:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="link in links">
   <p>
        <a data-ng-href="{{link.URL}}">{{link.URl}}</a>
   <p>
    // when link above is clicked, insert here textbox
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the combination of `ngClick` and `ngIf`:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="link in links">
   <p>
      <a data-ng-href="{{link.URL}}"
         data-ng-click="link.$open = !link.$open">{{link.URl}}</a>
      <input type="text" data-ng-if="link.$open" />
   <p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `link.$open` I understand that the link is the current item iterated from links but what about `.$open`?

Comment: @DavidDury arbitrary property name, you can call it however you want ( like a variable ). I prefix it with a `$` as a convention because angular strips all prefixed $ when sending data with $http

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize the fact that `ng-repeat` creates a scope for each item.
using a temporary variable `showHelpText`, this is how you can achieve it:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="link in links">
   <p>
        <a data-ng-href="{{link.URL}}" data-ng-click="showHelpText=!showHelpText">{{link.URl}}</a>
   <p>
    // when link above is clicked, insert here textbox
   <input type="text" data-ng-show="showHelpText">
</div>
```